# Hooks (Batched update cycle) - semantic error TS6133: '' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, hook

I am trying to provide a function of the previous state as the argument so state updates can be batched in a single update cycle `isOpen => index` but throws `semantic error TS6133: 'isOpen' is declared but its value is never read`

```
const initialState = -1;
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(initialState);
```

```
// Fails
const handleOpen = (index:number) => {
  if(index !== isOpen) {
    setOpen(isOpen => index);
  } else {
    setOpen(isOpen => initialState);
  }
};
```

but this passes

```
// Passes
const handleOpen = (index:number) => {
  if(index !== isOpen) {
    setOpen(index);
  } else {
    setOpen(initialState);
  }
};
```

Just confused, any curious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is trying to warn you that you defined a parameter for a function, but then never used it. Usually, writing code that does such a thing (ignores an explicitly defined parameter) is a mistake.

This time, with your code, it's not a mistake, and you know it. You can fix it by not defining a parameter:

```
setOpen(() => index);
```

Or by prefixing the parameter with `_`, which tells TypeScript "Yes, I know this parameter isn't being used, it's not a mistake":

```
setOpen(_isOpen => index);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Ahh typescript